# Ubuntu can not access other ubuntu hdd which is external

Tags: 14.04, command-line, partitioning, permissions, hard-drive

I had 14.04 ubuntu and my laptop crashed. I need to save data from there.

So i created a ubuntu 14.04 live usb and put in into my desktop and boot from it. I can see my hdd now (i connected via usb with box).

But it says you dont have permission. What can i do now?

It shows me two drives there both are 20 gb. I think one is copy of other, i dont know why it created two drives. You can see in image first. [my drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhdLD.png)

In one drive, i see 4 folders and all of them are empty. they are caneraydin,jhipster,app.lotsfound

I am seeing those via folder opening , not command line.

I dont want to go inside folders. i want to copy it all. 40 gb is not so high. please help. i am in internet cafe and lots of money i spent :/ and i asked him to remove windows so that i can use ubuntu live so it is really  bad for me each minute.

And also i am on live ubuntu cd so i dont know if i can make from here such commands.

i try this

```
sudo chown -R yourusername: /media/mountpoint
```

but not working :(

edit: now i have internet in ubuntu pc. as you can see in the picture, i have two drivers. in one i can see lots of folders  but i dont know them. others, i cant see inside.

when i  go inside `caneraydin` in left, there are two folders. one is readme other is `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop`

inside readme:

```
    THIS DIRECTORY HAS BEEN UNMOUNTED TO PROTECT YOUR DATA.

From the graphical desktop, click on:
 "Access Your Private Data"

or

From the command line, run:
 ecryptfs-mount-private
```

But when i do the command or clicked access private data, it says:

```
ERROR: Encrypted private directory is not setup properly
```

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$

those are my drives but i cant see my 20 gb i think

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1999 MB, 1999568384 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243 cylinders, total 3905407 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2eccfb97

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     3905406     1951679+   c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00037199

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    39063551    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        39063552    78125055    19530752   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3        78125056    86124543     3999744   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

also this did not do anything

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo find / -type d- iname '.Private' 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved.

sudo apt-get install -y ecryptfs-utils

i installed this

then this and it worked

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

INFO: Searching for encrypted private directories (this might take a while)...
^TINFO: Found [/media/ubuntu/139df09d-a0b5-4567-86c8-ebb26dd88d87/.ecryptfs/caneraydin/.Private].
Try to recover this directory? [Y/n]: y
INFO: Found your wrapped-passphrase
Do you know your LOGIN passphrase? [Y/n] y
INFO: Enter your LOGIN passphrase...
Passphrase: 
Inserted auth tok with sig [2c6b7102bf504377] into the user session keyring
INFO: Success!  Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.IFHvQShg].

it put all data encrypted inside tmp